# PHP wbepage file is still read after chmod 000 command on Linux

Tags: php, linux

I try to set all people can not read the file on my apache server so I run the command for example.php such as chmod 000 example.php, but I can still read it
on chrome browser. Why ? When Editing the example.php file, and save it again,
now it can NOT be read on browser. Why ?
It seems the chmod command effect is effective after the file is edit and saved again, otherwise the permission of the file is still the one before the chmod 000. Is it right ? If so, that may be issue, because that is impossible to edit and save many files again after chmod 000 to the files.

It is the issue to related to file or user id to linux system, please advise

But on the command-line console, the chmod 000 it works right away without doing any edit or save operation again to the files as above. Why ?

Comment: Is the file cached by the browser? Is the server running as root?

Comment: I check even clear all cache browser that doesn't help, and be reminded the file is in php  that won't create any cache as html file since php program need to run in the sever and echo output from the server

Comment: The server is running the on apache and set user and group for my username in httpd.conf for virtual host

Comment: Is it related to php and httpd.conf setup, CGI issue ?

Answer (score 1):

for php file, it needs to restart httpd after chmod operation.After that, the file can NOT be read by chmod 000. For other text file such as junk.txt, it is no need to restart and it response right away to chmod operaton